# No API or Deploy tabs in the Blockchain service UI

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I have been following through the instructions for the 'learn chaincode' example in the Bluemix Blockchain service, but what I am seeing the console does not match up to the instructions.
I only see 3 tabs, 'Network', 'Live Logs' and 'Blockchain', but the instructions talk about an 'APIs' and 'Deploy' tab.
Has something changed or got broken?

Comment: Hey Andy, can you provide a link to the example your are following? Are you following the tutorial on Github?

Comment: I am following the [hello chaincode](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/ibmblockchain_tutorials.html#hellocc) example. Yesterday when I opened the monitor page there were no APIs and Deploy tabs.....today they are there! Will comment back here if the problem happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are APIs. You should be able to access them in the API Tab within the Blockchain Service Dashboard.